# Alterself and reinterpretation of it's abilities

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, flight

Since alterself in 2nd edition would allow you to gain the natural abilities and movements of other bipedal anthropomorphic creatures.    IN 5th edition is allows for the aquatic movement (like sea elves, triton, etc..) but since Aarakora and Abyssal Tieflings can have wings as well and are also 5th edition critters.  **Do you all feel that in the current edition that flight can be granted as and alterself ability?   Perhaps with penalized movement as it was the same in 2nd ed?**   Also, yes fly is third level but you don't fall out of the sky at 1/2 hp with the Fly spell and you feather fall to the surface too at certain heights and you move faster and it can affect multiple people at higher castings. So i don't see this as an overlap.

Comment: Welcome to the stack Tom! Take the [tour] when you have a moment. The way you’ve worded your question seems to be somewhat opinion based (“do you feel”, “perhaps it’s like 2e?”). However, your question seems to be essentially the same as “can alter self give flight”, which has been asked before, so I’ve closed this as a duplicate of that question. For more info about asking questions, see [this help article](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).